# vsftpd - Can't login with a custom shell enabled

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, ftp, vsftpd

I set up vsftpd on my Ubuntu 20.04 server. Everything worked fine, I was even able to configure TLS. Now, I don't want the users to use SSH. I also disabled SFTP because of that. I don't want to disable SSH for these users because I want them to use it for some basic tools like change the password, etc. So, I've created a custom shell with these tools. However, when I enable this shell for the users, they can't log in to FTP. It just shows "login incorrect".

Why does vsftpd do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://linux-tips.com/t/users-with-bin-false-shell-to-login-on-vsftpd/200) article, vsftpd config file has a line:

```
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

This points to vsftpd pam service, which only allows valid shells.

So, if you comment out this line:

```
auth   required    pam_shells.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` and then restart the vsftpd service (`systemctl restart vsftpd` or `service vsftpd restart`), users will be able to log in.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: @user.dz Oh yeah I forgot :)